# Why does this regex not find anything in this text?

Tags: python, regex

```
title = 'Pokemon 1st Edition Alakazam 1/102 Base Set Mint Psa 9 Spanish no shadowless #1'

regex_set_search = 'psa\d?\d\d?'
set_number_match = re.search(regex_set_search, title, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(set_number_match)
```

Hello, I'm trying to pull out of the title variable either "psa 9", "psa 10", "PsA 1", "PSA 7". In this particular case I want to return "Psa 9". For some reason the above code is only returning None when I run it against the text sample. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You missed the space between psa and the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
import re
title = 'Pokemon 1st Edition Alakazam 1/102 Base Set Mint Psa 9 Spanish no shadowless #1'
 
regex_set_search = r'\bpsa\s*\d+'
set_number_match = re.search(regex_set_search, title, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(set_number_match.group())
```

With `r'\bpsa\s*\d+'`, you can match `psa` word, `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces and `\d+` matches one or more digits.

With `set_number_match.group()`, you get the value matched.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/YWdWQQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
re.findall(r'(?i)\bPSA\b\s\d+',title)
```

Comment: Use `\d+` to match one _or more_ digits. Also, the second `\b` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import re

title = 'Pokemon 1st Edition Alakazam 1/102 Base Set Mint Psa 9 Spanish no shadowless #1' 
regex_set_search = '\bpsa \d+'
set_number_match = re.search(regex_set_search, title, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(set_number_match.group())
```

Output:

```
Psa 9
```

Comment: It's better to start this pattern with `\b` to avoid matching other words that end with "psa".

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks for your advice!